# Spanish keyboard layout without ñ in Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard

I am used to the Spanish layout for programming and it is really hard for me to use anything else. I can use most European keyboards fine since they have the same number of keys by setting the layout to Spanish in Windows and it works as if the keyboard was Spanish since all they key match.

Unfortunately, English keyboards are missing an extra key next to the L where the Ñ is and when an English keyboard is is set to Spanish layout, all they keys for programming get messed up because of the missing key. They have some strange layout where all keys are there through combinations of modifier keys, e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd>, etc., but they are moved.

Is it possible to have a customized layout in Windows with a Spanish layout and English keyboard where the Ñ key is simple removed? Remove the extra key I don’t use and keep all the symbols in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another keyboard layout to your current language settings, but that would surely mess up other keys that no longer will represent the symbols that are written on the key.

If that's ok for you, and you have windows 10, go to Language Settings, choose your language, Options, and add Spanish keyboard layout.
For more detail go [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-keyboard-layout-windows-10)

Comment: I know about changing the layout. The problem is that the keys are all mingled because the english keyboard has one less key. I need a customized layout that behaves as the spanish key by key with the missing key (Ñ) simply removed. I think I need to use a third party tool to create such unfortunately.